# I want to hide tab content of previously opened tab on clicking next tab?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have 3 tabs suppose A,B and C. When user clicks on tab A its content must show, then user click on tab B the previously opened tab A content should hide and tab content of B must show and same for tab C.

this functionality should work on any randomly selected tabs.

Any Idea to perform this?

This is mine code:

```
>  jQuery('.view.view-user-info-page-mobile-view-responsive.view-display- id-block_1').hide();
         >jQuery('.view.view-display-id-block_2').hide();
> jQuery('#block-user-form').hide();


     >jQuery('#kes').toggle(function(){
     >jQuery('.view.view-display-id-block_1').show();       
     >},
     >function(){
     >jQuery('.view.view-display-id-block_1').hide();
     >});


     >jQuery('#bookmark').toggle(function(){
     >jQuery('.view.view-display-id-block_2').show();       
     >},
     >function(){
     >jQuery('.view.view-display-id-block_2').hide();
     >});
```

But Its not working:(

Comment: Sure--use jQuery UI or Bootstrap tabs.

Comment: please see the answer i posted

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample this should work i have used a dummy html for example:

it is just removal and addition of class:

$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

```
$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

$(this).addClass('current');
$("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
```

})

Please click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ab6zs2/) to see the demo

this is the HTML that i have used: you can view the complete code in the jsfiddle link

```
<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

</div>
```